# Office 2016 files won't allow editing from SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-2016, windows10

We have currently upgraded some PC's/Laptops from Office 2013/Windows 2007 to Office 2016/Windows 10, we are now experiencing, with those users, not being able to check out/edit files in Office 2016 that are opened from SharePoint 2013. The file opens up in the client but with a yellow label with the option to Edit the Document. If the users click "Edit Document" they get the error below.

[image]

SharePoint 2013 - Current Build 15.0.4893.1000 (January 2017) - Production Enviornment (No Dev)

Steps Taken:

1. Cleared Cache on Office Web Apps Server & All SharePoint Servers with IISReset
2. Checked Server & SharePoint logs, with no mention of the error occurring
3. Office 2016/Windows 10 install are fresh installs
4. Verified users access and ability to check out and edit
5. Verified users can check out and edit in the browser
6. Checked Event logs on the local PC and no errors were found

Comment: You can dig deeper by installing Fiddler on your Client. Post Fiddlers output here if you need further help.